# Many-to-many table as model with extra column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, many-to-many

I have a code-first MVC4 C# application with these two models

```
public class ClassRoom {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }
}

public class Pupil {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PupilName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClassRoom> ClassRooms { get; set; }
}
```

This is a part of the context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
    .HasMany(l => l.ClassRooms)
    .WithMany(o => o.Pupils)
    .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("PupilID")
        .MapRightKey("ClassRoomID")
        .ToTable("PupilClassRoomMM"));
```

Therefore there is a many-to-many table called "PupilClassRoomMM".

This all worked fine, but now I want to add a column to the PupilClassRoomMM-table.
I tried to make this Model, but the Add-Migration doesn't get it.

```
public class PupilClassRoomMM
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ClassRoomID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PupilID { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

The error is:

```
"PupilClassRoomMM: Name: The EntitySet 'PupilClassRoomMM' with schema 'dbo' and
table 'PupilClassRoomMM' was already defined.
Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table."
```

How can I add a field to an already existing many-to-many table (I don't want to lose its data).

Comment: You'd need to model it as two one-to-many relationships instead of one many-to-many. You need the inbetween class anyway.

Comment: The disadvantage of using two one-to-many relationships is that you can't use ClassRoom.Pupils anymore. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: Well, if you do `ClassRoom.Pupils` how would you access `IsPrimary`? EF can't map two different models to the same table, because it wouldn't know what to do with `IsPrimary` when you add a new Pupil to a classroom. It needs to be an intermediate class